# Outlook forwarding in shared mailbox deletes emails

Tags: exchange, outlook, rules, office365, shared-mailbox

I have the following Situation which I do not understand:

**Situation until now**
1. I have a shared o365 mailbox "AppSupport"

2. Within the mailbox there is a rule prefixing the subject line with "[AppSupport]" - this works fine
   [image: prefix example]
3. After prefixing the mail, it should be forwarded to an external Jira adress but remain within the application support mailbox for applying other Rules
   We used to do this with the "Connected Account setting" which worked fine.
   [image: mail forwarding page]

**Issue**
Just recently however, it forwarded the mails before adding the prefix so the tickets went into the wrong queue in Jira.

Because of that, I changed the forward into a second rule where I can set the priority:
[image: outlook rules overview]
[image: redirect rule]

- the first rule applies the prefix (working)
- the second rule forwards the email (working)

**BUT** after a successful forward or redirect, the email is deleted. I can not find the email in sent items, junk or deleted items. Its just not there in the inbox. However, the ticketsystem receives the email successfully.

Furthermore, when I add another action such as "after forwarding, mark the mail as read" the email is no longer forwarded. Instead a warning is displayed saying that external forwarding is prohibited, eventhough an exception is made within exchange online:
[image: Blocked mail message]
[image: Remote Domains]

Does anybody kow why the email is deleted without a sign of it and how I can stop that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi,

Did you configure a transport rule and an inbox rule like that:

1. Transport Rule: If the recipient is “Application Support”, Redirect the message to “jira service”
2. Inbox Rule for “Application Support” or “jira service”: Apply this rule after the message arrives from “Sender’s mailbox”, mark it as read.

Right?

Then I tried to configure them and use one mailbox named “Admin” to send an email to “Application Support”.

After that, the “jira service” mailbox received this email in its inbox(marked as read) and no messages in the sent items/inbox/junk/Deleted Items of “Application Support”.
In this progress, I didn’t receive any warning like yours.

I referred to one Microsoft document about mail flow rule, it says that “The message isn’t delivered to the original recipients, and no notification is sent to the sender or the original recipients  when you configured ‘Redirect’”.

More details about **Mail Flow Rule**: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/policy-and-compliance/mail-flow-rules/actions?view=exchserver-2019

Best regards,

Ivan Wang